# Best way to only list files that I own

Tags: command-line, files, ls, ownership

What would be the best shell command "one liner" that I could use to list all of the files in a directory, only showing those that I own?

Answer (score 15):

A short one-liner would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -user $USER
```

If you're looking in the current directory, you can omit the `.`. If you don't know whether `$USER` is available, you can replace it with `$LOGNAME` or `$(whoami)`.

Add `-ls` to show file details, e.g.:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -user root -ls
```

If you want to supply custom flags to `ls` you can use it via `-exec`:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -user root -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(In that case the `-d` flag to `ls` is required to list directories as themselves and not their content.)

Comment: It's better to use `$LOGNAME` as it's guaranteed to contain the user's login name on all Unices.  `$USER` may not exist everywhere on non-Linux Unices.

Comment: Also, rather than `-exec ls ...` you could use `-ls`.

Answer (score 4):

Use below command

```
[username@localhost~]$ find / -user username -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

find all file in the whole system owned by username. If you find  from specific directory just replace the location / .

```
[username@localhost~]$ find /path/of/direcotry -user username -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

NB:2>/dev/null nullify the error output.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to look recursively. Also, your first example repeats file names unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify the format of the output, you could also do this with ls and grep:

```
ls -lG | grep username
```

First we use ls with the -l parameter, to get the listing which includes username and groupname.

Then we prune the groupname from the result with the -G parameter.

After that, we simply pipe it to grep and get all of the results with the desired username.

**EDIT**:
As pointed out in the comments, this is **not a safe** or bulletproof solution - however, depending on your circumstances, it might be a quick & dirty one.
Interactively, it might be acceptable, but you should not use it in any scripts!

Comment: You [really shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/2465).

Comment: Not to mention that this will find files named `username`, or `foousername` or owned by `username2`.

Comment: I agree that this answer is not safe. Anyways, this is what I'm always doing interactively, `ll | grep user`. Most of my interactive `grep` usage is not rock solid but less typing is more important here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in ./*; do [ -f "$i" ] && [ -O "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done

find . ! -name . -prune -user "$(who -m)" -type f
```

Are the two ways that Will list out plain files in the current directory that you own.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you could do that using the [glob qualifier `u`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

> `u`*id*
>
> files owned by user ID *id* if that is a number. Otherwise, *id* specifies
>   a user name: the character after the '`u`' will be taken as a separator
>   and the string between it and the next matching separator will be
>   taken as a user name. The starting separators '`[`', '`{`', and '`<`' match
>   the final separators '`]`', '`}`', and '`>`', respectively; any other
>   character matches itself. The selected files are those owned by this
>   user. For example, '`u:foo:`' or '`u[foo]`' selects files owned by user
>   '`foo`'.

so e.g. with user `ID`

```
print -rl ./*(u1027)
```

or with user name

```
print -rl ./*(u_yourusernamegoeshere_)
```

As usual, you can combine it with other qualifiers, modifiers etc e.g. to list only regular files, hidden or not, owned by user with `UID` `1027` and sorted by their `mtime`:

```
print -rl ./*(.Domu1027)
```